# Problems retrieving a record from CloudKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, cloudkit

Having problems retrieving a record from CloudKit..

My `firstName` and `lastName` of my `CKRecord` are showing up as "N/A" which the safety value from a nil coalescing as you'll see below

I double and triple checked (and beyond) that all the spellings were right.. so I'm good there. Here is my retrieve method..

```
   func getProfile() {

    //GETTING USER RECORD ID

    CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID { id, error in
        guard let id = id, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return }
        
    //GETTING RECORD ID

        CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: id) { record, error in
            guard let record = record, error == nil else { return }
            
            let profileReference = record["userProfile"] as! CKRecord.Reference
            let profileRecordID = profileReference.recordID
            print("Profile reference is",profileReference)

    //PASSING REFERENCE TO GET CLIENT SIDE MODEL

            CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: profileRecordID) { profileRecord, error in
                guard let profileRecord = profileRecord, error == nil else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
    //FOR SOME REASON MY PROFILE IS NOT RECEIVING THE RIGHT VALUES FOR FIRST AND LAST NAME, IT JUST SHOWS "N/A"

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let profile = Profile(record: profileRecord)
                    print("Retrieved Record is: ",profileRecord)
                    print("Retrieved name is: \(profile.firstName)")
                    firstName = profile.firstName
                    lastName = profile.lastName
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the model..

```
struct Profile {
let profileID: CKRecord.ID
let firstName: String
let lastName: String


init(record: CKRecord) {
    profileID = record.recordID
    firstName = record["firstName"] as? String ?? "N/A"
    lastName = record["lastName"] as? String ?? "N/A"
   
}
```

}

Comment: Use `CKQuery` and `CKQueryOperation`.

Comment: @ElTomato I just did that and it was so easy.. I wonder why the guy who created this tutorial I got this from used this method?

Comment: Ah, actually because he is getting the specific `Profile` attached to the current User..